# I added writing to external storage permission to the manifest file eventhough logcat is saying no permissions to write. how to resolve it

Tags: android

here is my Logcat message

```
                                             java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/0F0D-0A0C/Download/notice.php: Neither user 10082 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
```

I am trying to download a file from the external storage, I gave the path of the file, My downloading file code is

```
TextView downloadlink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.downloadlink);
    downloadlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myHTTPUrl = "http://192.168.122.1/notice.php";
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myHTTPUrl));
            request.setTitle("File download");
            request.setDescription("File is being downloaded...");
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myHTTPUrl,null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myHTTPUrl));
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
```

manifest file permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: on marshmallow you have to define permission run time please see this like http://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/4146722

Comment: Can you show manifest file?

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` allows an application to write to external storage.
So add following permission in your AndroidManifest:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Try adding READ external storage as well!

Comment: getting same error. after adding READ external storage..

Comment: Are you testing your app on Marshmallow?

Comment: yes, using 5554:nexus_5_API_23 emulator

Answer (score 1):

please check your app is currently running in MarshMallow or higher, then need to check dangerous permissions on runtime. Please include it on MainActivity. and you can call it from anywhere.

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

public boolean checkPermission()
{
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("To download a file it is necessary to allow required permission");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

here check permission is already granted or not, if app is currently running in marshmallow or higher then check it as. here i changeed your code like this.

```
TextView downloadlink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.downloadlink);
downloadlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(checkPermission()){

          downloadFile();
        }  
    }
});
```

your downloading code is put in a method as

```
downloadFile(){
    String myHTTPUrl = "http://192.168.122.1/notice.php";
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myHTTPUrl));
        request.setTitle("File download");
        request.setDescription("File is being downloaded...");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myHTTPUrl,null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myHTTPUrl));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

if already granted permission then download code will work otherwise it then call to the override method 'onRequestPermissionsResult()'

here below give that override method

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                downloadFile();
            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

please try this, then it will work